# How to make the Node.js serve-static package work with network folders?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

This is using Node.js v6.9.1 on Windows 7.

I am trying to serve static files from a network folder. This is the relevant bit of my code:

```
var listener = require('express')();
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');

listener.use('/whatever', serveStatic('T:/shared folder'));
```

But when I send a request to '/whatever', I get this error message:

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'T:\shared folder'
```

However, if instead I try serving from 'C:/local folder' (i.e. a folder on the same machine as Node.js is running on), it works perfectly.

How do I make serve-static work correctly with network folders?

UPDATE: The problem only happens when I run this code as part of a Windows Service. If I run it from the command line ("npm start"), it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use a UNC path instead of "T:". Windows services don't have access to mapped drives.